# meaning of "takes"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

What does **"takes"** mean in this context?

Alys includes this mobile writing in a so-called ‘personal repertoire of possible behaviour while walking the streets of London Town’. It forms the final section of the publication, Seven Walks, which documents a major ‘London project’ commissioned by Artangel and is made up of a range of discrete if thematically linked **‘takes’** on the city. Walks as **takes**.

Answer (score 3):

In this context **takes** means viewpoints about / on the city. The author's (author of Seven Walks) opinion / point of view / perspective is the meaning of **takes** in this context.

One meaning of take is (as defined in google):

> a particular version of or approach to something - "his own whimsical take on life". Synonyms include: view of, version of, interpretation of, etc.

This was found when I googled 'takes meaning'. I found it under 'noun - point 1'

Comment: Good answer;upvote worthy. Possibly related to the idiom *the take away*, meaning what's learned or understood from some situation.

Comment: Thank you @deadrat, means a lot :) And you are right about it being possibly related to _the take away_ though it is slightly different as you have already pointed out